# Azure DevOps YAML run step if variable not equal null - how to reference yaml variable in condition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to run this step in a template if the number variable has a value.  Issue seems to be that even when set, like below, variables.number still seems to be empty.  I think I need another way to reference this variable?  I think this would work if I set the variable via the GUI but doesn't seem to pick it up from the YAML.  Does anybody know?

**YAML**

```
stages:
- stage: Run
  variables:
    - name: number
      value: '123'
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - template: .\run.yml
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
- ${{if ne(variables.number, '')}}:
    - powershell: Write-Host "Its working!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use it like this:

```
stages:
- stage: Run
  variables:
    - name: number
      value: '123'
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
    - ${{if ne(variables.number, '')}}:
       - template: .\run.yml
```

Variables is not accessible from the template.

Answer (score -1):

> Azure DevOps YAML run step if variable not equal null - how to reference yaml variable in condition

You need to pay attention to **the equivalence of single quotes**.

Since you set the comparison value to be empty `''`, then your variable needs to be quoted `'variables.number'` , otherwise its condition is always `False`:

```
- ${{if ne('variables.number', '')}}:
```

My test YAML scripts:

```
stages:
- stage: Run
  variables:
    - name: number
      value: '123'
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
        - template: child.yml
```

child.yml:

```
steps:
- ${{if ne('variables.number', '')}}:
    - script: echo works fine.
```

It works fine on my side.

[image]

Comment: With `- ${{if ne('variables.number', '')}}:` you are comparing the literal value `variables.number` to an empty string, which is indeed not equal.
However, you want to compare the value of the variable (`123`) to an empty string. Your code is not doing that - "It works fine on my side." is only because your comparison is hardcoded to be unequal. The answer from @Krzysztof looks correct.